# How to make splash screen show for 5 seconds and then disappear in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

I am creating a splash screen component that I want to run when the app is first launched for at least 5 seconds and then displays another component/screen.

I just started with react-native yesterday so I still don't know how to do complicated things such as this without causing errors. I managed to make it appear once the application is opened but it only shows for a split second.

here is my code:

App.js

```
const App = () => { 

   const [isFirstLaunch, setIsFirstLaunch] = React.useState(null);

   useEffect(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value => {
          if(value == null){
            
            AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched','true');
            setIsFirstLaunch(true);
          }else{
            setIsFirstLaunch(false);
          }
      })
   },[]);

 
  
   if (isFirstLaunch == null){
     return (
       <SplashScreen/>
     )
   }else if(isFirstLaunch == true){
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
       
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard">
        
         <WelcomeStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen}/>
         <WelcomeStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
         </Drawer.Navigator>
      
     </NavigationContainer>
           
         )
   }else{
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
       
        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Dashboard">
           <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={LandingScreen} options={{ swipeEnabled:false

           }} />
         
         </Drawer.Navigator>
      
     </NavigationContainer>
           
         )
   }
    
 };
export default App;
```

SplashScreen.js

```
const SplashScreen = () => {

    return (
        
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
            <Image source ={require('../assets/Dilmune-logo1.png')}
            style={styles.logo}
            resizeMode="stretch"
            />
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

export default SplashScreen;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along this line

```
    const [showSplash, setShowSplash] = useState(true);
     useEffect(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('alreadyLaunched').then(value => {
          if(value == null){
             setTimeout(() => {
          setShowSplash(false)
        },5000)
            AsyncStorage.setItem('alreadyLaunched','true');
            setIsFirstLaunch(true);
          }else{
            setIsFirstLaunch(false);
          }
      })
   },[]);
    
  

    if (isFirstLaunch == null && showSplash){
         return (
           <SplashScreen/>
         )
       } add
```

Comment: it is now conflicting with the other useEffect that i have, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

you probably will need something like this on your `App` component:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
const timeout = useTimeout(()=> setShowSplash(false),5000)
return () => clearTimeout(timeout)
}, [])
```

then, you render the splash or the app accordingly.

Comment: can you tell me exactly where to put this code? react native is different you cant just put code anywhere and expect it to work sadly. please if its not too much trouble can u point where i should include this code?